# SSL error on HTTP GET

Tags: java, ssl

I am getting

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Things i have tried:
  1. Adding cert to my keystore
  2. Using a custom TrustModifier to not validate. This cause the SSL error to change to http 401 error

Here is my code

```
URL website = new URL(urlpath);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //TrustModifier.relaxHostChecking(conn);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        copyStream (is, out);
        out.close();
```

Comment: "1. Adding cert to my keystore" that should work, if done correctly (you only need to add the certificate authority - the root - certificate, but if it is a self-signed certificate, then it is the root). Show how you did it in your question, because this is the right solution. "2. Using a custom TrustModifier to not validate. This cause the SSL error to change to http 401 error" this is the insecure, incorrect way, which may allow an attacker to hijack the connection. Still for testing, if you get a "401" error, it worked. 401 just means that you weren't correctly authenticated to the website.

Comment: i went to the website that is the `url` in chrome. Then i clicked the LOCK icon to download the cert. I then added it to the file called `cacert` in the `JRE`